# Tax Residency under FATCA and CRS

Tags: income-tax, investing, india, germany

I am an Indian citizen and a PR holder in Germany. I am opening a depot account in Germany and there is a question about Tax residency. I would like to know if I am a resident for tax purposes only in Germany or both in India and Germany.

p.s. I have some savings in India and the interest from those savings are exempted from tax in India.

Comment: You would be classified as NRI for India tax purposes. Ensure that you have converted your savings account to NRO.

Comment: Yes, I do have NRE and NRO accounts. All I want to know is how to answer the tax residency question while opening the depot account in Germany.